# Java - adding array rows and columns

Tags: java

I need to generate a random 10x10 array and then add rows and columns of that array, so the sum of row elements is displayed at the beginning of each row and the sum of column elements is displayed at the top of each column. Is there a simple way to do it?

Here is the code:

```
class Sum {

    public static void main(String Args[]) {
        int row_num = 10;
        int col_num = 10;
        int[][] arr = new int[row_num][col_num];
        int a;
        int b;
        int row_sum;
        int[] col_sum = new int[col_num];

        // Generating array

        for (a = 0; a < row_num; a++) {
            for (b = 0; b < col_num; b++) {
                arr[a][b] = (int) (10 * Math.random());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Array:");

        row_sum = 0;

        for (a = 0; a < row_num; a++) {
            for (b = 0; b < col_num; b++) {
                col_sum[b] = col_sum[b] + arr[a][b];
                System.out.print(arr[a][b] + "  ");
                row_sum = row_sum + arr[a][b];
            }
            System.out.println("   " + row_sum);
            row_sum = 0;
        }

        for (a = 0; a < col_num; a++)
            System.out.print(col_sum[a] + " ");

    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, this is pretty simple stuff; probably not more than 10  to 20 lines within some *main* method. So there is a simple way: you start trying.

Comment: I was able to generate array, then do sum of row elements, but I can't figure out how to display sum at the beginning of row and on the top of column.

Comment: You need to show us what you have done so far, and then point out the specific thing in your code that you are struggling with.

Comment: What do you mean by display anyway? I assume you're printing to the console? Show us the code where you do that.

Comment: I don’t regard Stack Overflow as a code writing service.

Comment: I am going to assume that you can write this code yourself until you tell me *exactly* what about it you are having a problem with. “Is there a simple way…?” is far from enough.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. (quoted from [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: Also see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Thx for the code. Next time please have your IDE format/indent the code properly before you post it (this time I did it for you).

Comment: OK, thanks for clue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code. You’re closer than I thought when I read the question without the code.

I think the easier part is printing the row sum at the beginning of each row. You will need to separate you inner `for` loop into two `for` loops after each other. At present, the inner `for` loop both prints the numbers and sums them. Instead, do one `for` loop that only sums the numbers. Then print the sum. Then the second `for` loop will print each number in the row.

The idea for printing the column sums above the columns is similar, only this time you are replacing the *outer*  for loop with two for loops, one for summing and one for printing the array. See if you cannot get it to work along these lines (I am deliberately still leaving some thought work for you).